# VirtualBox: Cannot install Ubuntu14.04 on Mac

Tags: macos, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run a **virtual machine** on my Mac pro using *VirtualBox*.

Here is the basic infos about it:

[image]

When I start it, and select the optical disk file. (**ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso**)

It causes errors:

[image]

Any solution to this?

Comment: can you specify the steps you followed?Did you try to download again the .iso file?

Comment: I would say that you might have a corrupted .iso. Another option it would be to create a bootable file from the .iso and use that for the installation.

Comment: yes, the .iso optical disk file is broken.

Comment: So, did it work with a new one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow these steps instead of double click on the Ubuntu-VM icon and then choose the location of the .iso file:

1. At the VirtualBox Manager screen, select the newly created “Ubuntu
   Linux” virtual machine and click on the “Settings” button
2. Click on the “Storage” tab and next to “IDE Controller” click the + icon that looks like a CD to add a new IDE Controller
3. Click “Choose Disk” and  locate the Ubuntu ISO (named something like ”
   ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso”) that you downloaded earlier, then
   click “OK” and close out of Setting

Taken from [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/install-run-ubuntu-linux-virtualbox/)

Comment: i have tired this, but got same result.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad ISO, have you verified the signature?

If it does verify then I would go through the normal troubleshooting steps.

- restart virtual box
- restart your computer
- look for any software that could mess up reading iso's (some sort of 3rd party disk utility)